# grunt-concat separator option?

Tags: javascript, configuration, build, concatenation, gruntjs

how to specify a separator in this scenario:
I'm concatenating my files with grunt-concat this way:

```
concat: {
  options: {
    banner: '<%= banner %>',
    separator: ""
  },
  dist: {
    files:{
      '<%= distdir %>/public/scripts/ieditor.js': [
        'public/scripts/ieditor/vars.js',
        'public/scripts/ieditor/controllers/*.js',
        'public/scripts/ieditor/directives/*.js',
        'public/scripts/ieditor/app.js',
        'public/scripts/ieditor/services/*.js',
        'public/scripts/ieditor/filters/*.js'
      ],
      '<%= distdir %>/public/scripts/dashboard.js': [
        'public/scripts/dashboard/vars.js',
        'public/scripts/dashboard/controllers/*.js',
        'public/scripts/dashboard/directives/*.js',
        'public/scripts/dashboard/app.js',
        'public/scripts/dashboard/services/*.js',
        'public/scripts/dashboard/filters/*.js'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

what I want is to get a final result mapped to the original files like in compass when concatenating CSS files.
Example:

```
//####public/scripts/ieditor/vars.js###############
content of public/scripts/ieditor/vars.js
//####public/scripts/ieditor/controllers/a.js######
content of public/scripts/ieditor/controllers/a.js
//####public/scripts/ieditor/controllers/b.js######
content of public/scripts/ieditor/controllers/b.js
.....
```

So what's the name referring to the current file being concatenated so i can do something like this in the options area:

```
  options: {
    banner: '<%= banner %>',
    separator: "<%= current_file_name %>"
  },
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`process` option, specified as a function](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#custom-process-function), is your friend:

```
concat: {
  options: {
    process: function(src, filepath) {
      return '//####' + filepath + '\n' + src;
    }
  }
},
...
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, don't know why!? nothing is added by the process function.

Comment: Maybe `console.log()` can help you to find out if the function is being called? I'm on `grunt` 0.4.1 and `grunt-contrib-concat` 0.3.0, and it does work for me

Comment: Actually the function is being called I used the example in the docs, where it replaces all the 'use restrict' with one at the top, that did work but the `filepath` was not added.

Comment: Then, what are you getting as the value for the second parameter of the function?

Comment: Sorry, my grunt-contrib-concat was outdated I was using the v0.1.3 after updating it to v0.3.0 it worked.