# Having Grunt name files and include banners with source file names via Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs, lodash, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm trying to set up a customized Gruntfile.js to use as a boilerplate on future projects (mostly web performance optimization tasks).

The task most relevant to this question is concatenation. Here's the configuration of that task from a recent project:

```
concat: {
            css: {
                options: {
                    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n',
                },
                src: [
                     'wp-content/plugins/orangebox/css/orangebox.css', 
                     'wp-content/themes/caps/style.css', 
                     'styles.css', 
                     'contact.css', 
                     'pro_dropdown_2/pro_dropdown_2.css', 
                     'css/slider.css'
                ],

                dest: 'combined.<%= grunt.template.today("ddmmyyyy") %>.css'
            },

            js: {
                options: {
                    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %>-Version-<%= pkg.version %>-Compiled-<%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n',
                },

                src: [
                    'cformnkp.js',
                    'AC_RunActiveContent.js',
                    'js/moo_12.js',
                    'js/sl_slider.js',
                    'js/swfobject.js',
                    'scripts/*.js',
                    'pro_dropdown_2/*js'
                ],

                dest: 'concat.<%= grunt.template.today("ddmmyyyy") %>.js',
                separator: ";"
            }
        },
```

So that any other developers after me know what I did, I'd like to include a comment before each section of concatenated code (i.e. a 'banner') that would say what the original file name was before I concatenated them all.

It'd also be pretty cool if the new file was named obviously. For instance, if the concatenated JS file was `cformnkp-AC_RunActiveContent-moo_12-sl_slider-swfobject.js` (this is neglecting the dynamically added files, as well as the last specifically enumerated file but you get the idea).

I thought `<%= pkg.name %>` might accomplish this but it only inserts the name of my package as listed in `package.json`.

I can't fully make sense of the LoDash template documentation, and nothing on here seems to indicate how to do this even though is seems pretty straight-forward. A little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for **seperator** between each part of the code that includes original file path, you can use the `process` option of grunt-contrib-concat as mentioned in this question: [grunt-concat separator option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750017/grunt-concat-separator-option)

---

For a file name like `lib1-lib2-lib3.js`, what you could check out is the [grunt.file](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file) api page.

The `grunt.file.expand()` function takes a list of file patterns and return the complete list of file names that match (with path).

From there, some old fashioned Javascript code in **Gruntfile.js** will get the result you want.

Before `grunt.initConfig` :

```
var src = [
    'cformnkp.js',
    'AC_RunActiveContent.js',
    'js/moo_12.js',
    'js/sl_slider.js',
    'js/swfobject.js',
    'scripts/*.js',
    'pro_dropdown_2/*js'
];

// returns full list of .js files that matches your *.js
var complete_src = grunt.file.expand(src); 


var final_name = '';

// some string manipulations to get your the format you want 

for (var i = 0; i < complete_src.length; i++) {
    complete_src[i] = complete_src[i].substring(complete_src[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1, complete_src[i].length - 3);

}

var final_name = complete_src.join('-');
```

then:

```
    dist: {
        src: src ,
        dest: 'dist/'+final_name+'.js'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go over API docs in more detail but it looks like this will do exactly what I was looking for. If that is the case I'll mark it as correct then.

Comment: I was reviewing this code recently and reading up on `lastIndexOf`; I wish I could upvote this more. Thanks for your help with this.